# jQuery id class selctions ".click"

Tags: jquery, tags, click, css-selectors

```
<script>
    $( "#oth" ).click(function() {
        $( "#foli9" ).show( "slow" );
    });

    $( "#fam" ).click(function() {
        $( "#foli9" ).hide( 1000 );
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible where I have selected the id "#fam" to select multiple ids. like "#fam, #test, #another" ?

So on click it will apply to multiple ids?

Comment: I think using class instead of ids its a better approach, and also you should research a little bit before to ask this qustiong google: `select different ids jquery` first result `http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?

```
$("#fam, #test, #another").click(function() { ...
```

Should work fine.  See the jQuery API docs for [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jQuery uses css selectors, therefore you can comma-separate a list of selectors:

```
$( "#fam, #test, #another" ).click(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use multiple ids in a selector using jQuery.

You can use multiple ids like this:

```
$("#fam, #test, #another")
```

Another way would be to give a class name (same) to all three of them and do:

```
$(".your_class_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple selectors for the id work fine:

```
 $("#fam, #test, #another").on("click", function() { ... });
```

However, one has to make sure that the ids are unique. It thus might be more useful to define a common class (let's say `myClass`) for these three elements and use

```
 $(".myClass").on("click", function() { ... });
```

instead.